# Creating nested menu in django-cms

Tags: django-cms

In my base template, I'm showing the menu using the `show_menu` tag as follows:

```
{% show_menu %}
```

I created a template (`templateA.html`) and then created another template that inherits from it (`templateA1.html`), then I created pages from both templates in the admin area. However, the menu shows these page links along side one-another and not nested in a submenu.

So, how do I create nested pages that show up nested in the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nesting of your pages isn't dictated by template inheritance, it's decided by how you lay out your pages in the django-cms admin interface. You need to place the pages you create in the hierarchy that you wish to reflect in your menu:

[image]